# extract variables from an expression using javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, here is a string representing an expression:

```
var str = 'total = sum(price * qty) * 1.09875';
```

I want to extract variables (i.e., 'total', 'price' and 'qty' but not 'sum' since 'sum' is a function name) from this expression. What is the regexp pattern in javascript? Variable name consists of letters, digits, or the underscore, beginning with letters or the underscore.

Comment: it's easy to write one for this specific case, but very very hard to write a generalized version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
return "total = sum(price * qty) * 1.09875".match(/[a-z_]\w*(?!\w*\s*\()/ig);
```

Here,

1. `[a-z_]` matches 1 letter or 1 underscore,
2. `\w*` matches 0 or more letters, digits or underscore (`\w` means `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
3. `(?!…)` is a negative lookahead. The match will fail if the stuff inside is matched.
4. `\w*\s*\(` matches some letters, followed by some spaces, and then an `(`. This allows function names to be rejected.